# adding limits to daisy-chained query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, limit

Having inherited a project, I find code like this, to search for a set of records in the codebase:

```
Listing.category_id_equals(category_id).city_id_equals(city.id).end_date_greater_than(Time.now.utc).start_date_less_than(Time.now.utc).validated_equals(true)
```

This works, but is brittle, because if I want to not include any of the conditions, I need a new method. So, using proc's I now have :

```
 def self.for_cat_and_city cat=nil, city=nil
  base = proc { |o| o.end_date_greater_than(Time.now.utc).start_date_less_than(Time.now.utc).validated_equals(true)}
  city_query = proc { |o, city| o.city_id_equals(city.id)}
  cat_query = proc { |o, cat| o.category_id_equals(cat.id)}
  limit = proc { |o, limit| o.limit(limit)}
  unless cat.nil?
    return city_query.call(cat_query.call(base.call(Listing),cat), city) unless city.nil?
    return cat_query.call(base.call(Listing), cat)
  end
  return city_query.call(base.call(Listing), city) unless city.nil?
  return base.call(Listing)
end
```

Which works really well. But now I need to add a limit to the number of records. How can I do this easily within the bounds of what I'm doing above?

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding `limit` to the end of the chain, like this:

```
listings = Listing.category_id_equals(category_id).city_id_equals(city.id).end_date_greater_than(Time.now.utc).start_date_less_than(Time.now.utc).validated_equals(true).limit(30)
```

Does that work?

Comment: Well – I was also a bit late myself :)